# how to understand the nodejs code below?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

The code below is from `connect` which is a popular module in nodejs.

```
function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
}
```

I'm thinking for a long time, but I don't know how the function app executes. Is anyone familiar with the code ? Please tell me how it works. Thank you!

Comment: "*I don't know how the function app executes*" The `function app(...)` defined here doesn't execute. It isn't called here. Its properties are modified and then it's `return`ed.

Comment: I think, I know the answer, thank you for replying!

Comment: Yeah. The `function app` here is the value of `var app` [in the example](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#connect--), which is eventually passed to `http.createServer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely more to that code later on.

According to this [blog](http://www.charlesholbrow.com/posts/what-is-an-expressjs-app),

> The code above uses utils.merge to give app all the functionality of
>   the [Connect http server prototype](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/proto.js). This includes the .use, .handle,
>   and .listen methods.
>
> The app also merges [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Gozala/events) from the node.js events library.
>   EventEmitter is where app gets app.on and app.emit from.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! I know how the function app executes. Thank you!